# How could I merge duplicate elements from object arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have an object array, containing average name and group:

```
[
  {
     id: 'first',
     average: 4,
     name: 'John',
     group: 'alpha'
  },
  {
     id: 'second',
     average: 5,
     name: 'Frank',
     group: 'beta'
  },
  {
     id: 'third',
     average: 2,
     name: 'Marc',
     group: 'gamma'
  },
  {
     id: 'fourth',
     average: 3,
     name: 'David',
     group: 'alpha'
  },
]
```

I would like to merge them based on the same group,
so the expected would be:

```
[
  {
     average: 3.5,
     name: ['John', 'David'],
     group: 'alpha'
  },
  {
     average: 5,
     name: ['Frank'],
     group: 'beta'
  },
  {
     average: 2,
     name: ['Marc'],
     group: 'gamma'
  }
]
```

I've tried with reduce and double filters, but no success.. :/
How it could be done?!

Comment: This may help you:
let newObj = [...new Map((obj.map((x)=>{let z= {...x};obj.forEach((y)=> {if(z.group == y.group) {typeof(z.name) == 'string' ? (z.name = [y.name]) && (z.average = [y.average]) : (z.name.push(y.name)) && (z.average.push(y.average))}}); return [z.group, z]}))).values()];